# java GUI multi-threading with socket

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets

I am trying to make a GUI program which get data from TCP socket.
The problem is when I set up the socket, and then start it, GUI program freeze. 
I want add one more function that stop thread by using click event.

As I know I have to use EDT, I tried but doesn't work. Is there anyone who can help me?

Here's my code.

1. main

   ```
   public class ImageSplit {  
   static ImageViewerFrame program;
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  
   JPanel[] displayArray = new JPanel[100];   
   program = new ImageViewerFrame();

   EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

       @Override
       public void run() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           program.setVisible(true);
       }

   });
   }
   ```
2. frame

   ```
   void createMouseMenu() {
   final PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu();
   MenuItem grid = new MenuItem("Grid");
   MenuItem start = new MenuItem("Start");
   MenuItem stop = new MenuItem("Stop");
   menu.add(grid);
   menu.add(start);
   menu.add(stop);
   add(menu);

   mouseMenuHandler mousemenu = new mouseMenuHandler();

   grid.addActionListener(mousemenu);
   start.addActionListener(mousemenu);
   stop.addActionListener(mousemenu);

   addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
       public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
           if (e.getModifiers() == InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK)
               menu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
       }
   });
      }
   class mouseMenuHandler implements ActionListener {
   getInfo info;

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {// open grid setting
       if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Grid")) {
           gridSettingUI = new GridSetting(img);
           gridSettingUI.setVisible(true);
       } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Start")) {
           try {
               info = new getInfo(40000);//open socket
               info.run();
           } catch (IOException e1) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e1.printStackTrace();
           }
       } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Stop")) {
           System.out.println("stop");
           info.stop();
       }
   }
   }
   ```
3. socket Receiving

   ```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.net.ServerSocket;
   import java.net.Socket;



   public class getInfo implements Runnable{
   ServerSocket serverSocket;
   private boolean stopped=false;

   public getInfo(int port_num) throws IOException{
   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_num);
   }
   @Override
   public void run() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   while(!stopped){
   try {
   Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
   System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress()+ "connected");

   InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
   if(br.ready())
   {
   String line = br.readLine();
   System.out.println(line+"\n");
   }
   } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   }

   public void stop(){
   stopped = true;        
   }
   ```

}

Comment: 2. frame , I only attached the menu action parts. If you need full code, please let me know

Comment: *"As I know I have to use EDT, I tried but doesn't work. "* - No, this is in fact the opposite, you DON'T want to performing long running or blocking calls (like talking to a `Socket`) within the EDT

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, so I want to stop socket by using GUI event, but nothing work on my GUI. It's totally freeze

Comment: That's because you opened the Socket within the EDT...

Comment: Use a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for the socket work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
info = new getInfo(40000);//open socket
info.run();
```

In the lines above, you are *NOT* starting a thread, instead, you are just executing the `run()` method in the same thread (as it was any other method call).

Extend from `Thread`, then call `info.start()`.

See: *Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases* by Joshua Bloch and     Neal Gafter, [Puzzle #76](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=RM9sLE0ntQ0C&pg=RA1-PT216&lpg=RA1-PT216&dq=Java%20Puzzlers%20puzzle%2076&source=bl&ots=1_gHvcpjcQ&sig=oJLwQOn1Y1knE5ScIMco0LjJIxY&hl=it&sa=X&ei=GAwmVYOTDIWY8QXZ5YCQCA&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Java%20Puzzlers%20puzzle%2076&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library called Jexxus which lets you use sockets more easily. It will automatically do things on a different thread so your UI won't freeze. There's a little tutorial at the bottom of the page here:  https://github.com/mirraj2/Jexxus/tree/master